# Script not vocalizing the variable, but printing it out okay

Tags: bash, shell

```
#!/bin/sh
#Saying the system time out loud

time= date +"%T"

say The current time now is, $time. Bye.
```

The script is printing out the time, not saying it.

Comment: Script is not correct. Check syntax at shellcheck.net

Comment: Thank you for the response. That is a handy site. Looks like this is the corrected script? Still not working though!

#!/bin/sh
#Saying the system time out loud
var time=date +"%T"
say The current time now is, "$(time)". Bye.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to assign the variable as you can just include the output of `date` like this

```
#!/bin/sh
#Saying the system time out loud
say "The time is now $(date +%T). Thank you."
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a HereDoc like this ...

```
bash-3.2$ cat <<EOT
> The current time is now, `date +"%T"`
> EOT
The current time is now, 19:49:16
```

Comment: the backtick syntax is discouraged nowadays in favor of `$(...)`.  however it's worth noting that `say` will work with standard input, but only if command line arguments are not supplied, so a heredoc with command substitution would be an alternative

Comment: Yes good point, usually.  I noticed the OP's shebang was `/bin/sh` which may or may not be linked to bash.  I just wanted to be Borne Shell compatible just in case.

Answer (score 0):

> `time= date +"%T"`

you want to set `time` to the stdout of the `date` command, so you want `$(date +%T)` (the double quotes around `%T` aren't necessary as `%` doesn't have a special meaning in this context).

> printing out the time, not saying it."

Fixing your syntax , it works for me and recently vocalized the time as "twenty one forty six twenty seven" for example.

```
time=$(date +%T)
say the time is $time
```

Comment: Thank you. Not getting vocalization still. 
./currenttime.sh: line 4: date+%T: command not found

real 0m0.001s
user 0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s

This is the response now.

Comment: I added my exact commands.  You really need to get the syntax right on this for it to work the way you want.   `real 0m0.001s user 0m0.000s sys 0m0.000s ` this means you're *invoking* the `time` command  wich means you have a space somewhere in your `time` setting.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this worked. Thank you. :) Appreciate the help!

```
#!/bin/sh
#Saying the system time out loud

time=$(date +"%T")
say The time is now $time. Thank you.
```